# How to set an EditText's initial height while allowing it to expand when overflows

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am currently working on an android app and i'm having some problems with EditText.

I want to create an editText with an empty string starting off with the height equivalent to 1 or more lines and maintaining that height, but allowing it to grow when text starts to overflow beneath the current size.

I tried several things :

1. If I set the Edittext's size to a certain value, it doesn't grow... the previous lines just go up and become invisible
2. When I don't set the size and use the default height, then the edittext always starts off with the height of two lines, not 1 line.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use wrap content which should expand with the text

```
<EditText 
android:width = "match_parent"
android:height= "wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Yeah but creating an editText with an empty string using a  wrap content always create an editText with the height of two lines. I can't reduce it to 1 line high...

Comment: something else is going on then it shouldnt create 2 lines, i just tested this and it is only 1 lines high

Comment: thanks, think I should find what other problems there may be

Comment: post your code here and we can take a look and see if something looks weird

Answer (score 6):

How about using these option?

```
android:maxHeight="100dip"
android:minHeight="40dip"
```

MaxHeight will force your EditText's height no more than 100dip.

MinHeight will force your EditText's height minimum is 40dip.

Example)

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/somethingEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="56dip"
    android:maxHeight="200dip"
    android:minLines="1" />
```

This code will force your EditTex's height range to '56dip ~ 200dip'

Answer (score 5):

You can set minimum lines using minLines Property of edittext, also use height as wrap content to make it expandable.

```
<EditText 
android:width = "match_parent"
android:height= "wrap_content"
android:minLines="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else still having issue with this or with TextInputEditText in the material design? It seems like the internal padding for TextInputEditText is automatically adjusted even when setting explicit *android:textSize* *android:minLines* and *android:minHeight*. You still have to explicitly set the padding.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:minHeight="35dp"

        android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
        android:paddingVertical="0dp"/> 

        <!-- /\ Add the two lines above /\ -->

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```